Create a Pandas dataframe of normal estimates based on varying row requirements
I get that this will create a dataframe of a single sample:
samples = np.random.normal(loc=df_avgs['AVERAGE'][region], scale=df_avgs['STDEV'][region], size=1)

But I want to create a sample for each row, based on a condition. For instance, I have a df of means, stdev and a df of conditions.
df_avgs



REGION
AVERAGE
STDEV




0
-1.61
7.75


1
2.87
8.38


2
3.61
7.61


3
-10.26
9.19



df_conditions



ID
REGION_NAME




0
Region 0


1
Region 3


2
Region 2


3
Region 1


4
Region 1


5
Region 2


6
Region 3



How do I create a df of length(df_conditions) or just add a column to df_conditions, with samples based on the region?

IIUC, you can merge the two dataframes together and then, assign the values using list comprehension with a zip of two dataframe columns:
df_zip = df_conditions.assign(REGION=df_conditions['REGION_NAME'].str.extract('([0-9])').astype(int)).merge(df_avgs)

df_conditions['SAMPLES'] = [np.random.normal(loc=l, scale=s, size=1)[0] for l, s in zip(df_zip['AVERAGE'], df_zip['STDEV'])]

print(df_conditions)

Output:
   ID REGION_NAME    SAMPLES
0   0    Region 0  -2.475624
1   1    Region 3  -7.157439
2   2    Region 2  -4.563650
3   3    Region 1  -2.199240
4   4    Region 1   5.221416
5   5    Region 2   7.175620
6   6    Region 3 -22.775366


Thanks. I know the first line works and I am kind of upset I didn't think of taking that logical first step. Hard to really prove if the second step is working since it is creating samples. I probably need to create a df_avgs file with very different values to ensure.

Once you have merged the dfs, the means and stds can be passed as arrays:
df_conditions = (
    df_conditions.assign(
        REGION=df_conditions['REGION_NAME'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$').astype(int)
        )
    .merge(df_avgs, on='REGION')
    .assign(
        SAMPLES = lambda x: np.random.default_rng().normal(
            loc=x.pop('AVERAGE'), 
            scale=x.pop('STDEV'), 
            size=len(x.pop('REGION'))
            )
        )
    )

Output:
   ID REGION_NAME    SAMPLES
0   0    Region 0 -13.940460
1   1    Region 3 -14.353592
2   2    Region 2  -4.011282
3   3    Region 1   0.664078
4   4    Region 1  -1.276447
5   5    Region 2   5.210611
6   6    Region 3 -15.929978

Explanation / intermediate

Use Series.str.extract on df_conditions['REGION_NAME'] to extract the digits and assign as 'REGION' with df.assign.
Use df.merge to add columns 'AVERAGE' and 'STDEV' from df_avgs.

# merged

   ID REGION_NAME  REGION  AVERAGE  STDEV
0   0    Region 0       0    -1.61   7.75
1   1    Region 3       3   -10.26   9.19
2   2    Region 2       2     3.61   7.61
3   3    Region 1       1     2.87   8.38
4   4    Region 1       1     2.87   8.38
5   5    Region 2       2     3.61   7.61
6   6    Region 3       3   -10.26   9.19


Now, use np.random.Generator.normal (preferred to np.random.normal) with triple df.pop as we don't need the respective columns in the end result.


Data used
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'REGION': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}, 
        'AVERAGE': {0: -1.61, 1: 2.87, 2: 3.61, 3: -10.26}, 
        'STDEV': {0: 7.75, 1: 8.38, 2: 7.61, 3: 9.19}
        }

df_avgs = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'ID': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}, 
         'REGION_NAME': {0: 'Region 0', 1: 'Region 3', 2: 'Region 2', 3: 'Region 1', 
                         4: 'Region 1', 5: 'Region 2', 6: 'Region 3'}}
df_conditions = pd.DataFrame(data2)

